# absolute positioned child div width, getting out of relative positioned container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, position

I know it's very common question but could find the solution!
A div which has `position: relative` and a div inside it has `position: absolute` and `width: 100%` just overflowing it's parent. I don't know what's I'm missing.

[image]

what I have:

```
.parent-div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child-div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Note:** here parent div is bootstrap [`list-group-item`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/list-group/) element

[image: screenshot with code]

Any help would be appreciable. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Issue has been resolved! It's because of that `bootstrap group`. So, I've took another wrapper and let it's position `relative` and it's now working perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `box-sizing: border-box;` it Include padding and border in the element's total width and height:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see, the width on your parent div is missing, so the 100% width on the child div gets his own life.